# Bricked my computer, is there any way to get it back?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I recently installed Ubuntu, but grabbed the 32-bit by accident so I went back to Windows, and was like better remove the Ubuntu files, so I deleted that partition. I downloaded the 64-bit version and made it USB bootable. I proceeded to turn off my computer and plug in the USB to boot however I got the no such partition Grub rescue message. I was like I am dumb half to tell it to boot from the USB, so I turned off my computer and spammed F2 to get into BIOS, but I wasn't able to and the text that normally says press F2 to enter BIOS was gone. I am using the Lenevo IdeaPad n585 laptop. I also can't boot off of CD because I remember the boot list went:

Hard drive
External hard drive
USB
CD

If possible I would like to keep files, but wouldn't mind resetting if necessary. Another problem is that Lenevo uses a one key recovery thing which requires Windows to to be installed on a primary partition which I made logical to make a partition for Ubuntu. Please help. The warranty is out. Nothing I found helps. I do have another computer I can use if necessary, but it is an old Window XP computer.

Comment: Try to remove the battery for a few seconds, put it back in, power on your laptop and start spamming F2 at the same time. If you have Fast Boot enabled you've a very little time. The battery thing may sound a bit weird but it has worked for me once.

Comment: Tried the battery thing but didn't work.

Comment: Try holding down F2, then power-up.

Comment: http://www.lenovo.com/shop/americas/content/user_guides/n580_ug_en.pdf on page 26 has directions to use the built in restore without windows.

Comment: I solved it but none of those answer you gave worked will post the real solution in 5 hours because below 10 rep.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to remove the hard drive so there was no bootable options. This allowed me to access the bios again and then put in the usb. I also took all the information from my internal hard drive and transferred it to an external one I had lying around. I also plugged in the external hard drive I then reinstalled the new version of ubuntu that I originally tried to install onto the hard drive I then retransferred the boot stuff back to my original hard drive and it now boots to grub fine again. P.s. Don't call Lenovo support all they did was say we can sell you a $9 windows recovery disk which I told them won't work because it is below the hard drive in  boot order.